# How can I get the Session values after payment? (CakePHP-Paypal Hosted Solution)

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP for my application and I was able to integrate the Paypal hosted solution. Users are successfully redirected to Paypal to complete their payment. Once they have completed, they are returned to my website.

At first, it was taking the user to the login page (as the session was getting removed). To prevent this, I have opened the Paypal page in a new window. Now they are not being asked to login again and keeping the $this->Session->read('Auth.User') intact. However, it is not remembering any other session data. For example, I had a session variable 'invoice_number' which is not available after they are returning from the Paypal website.

I have noticed that the session id doesn't stay the same before and after they completed the payment.

I have changed the core.php to reduce the session security by setting it to low, increased the session time, and I have also modified so that it will only start the session if no session id was found (saw this on a CakePHP ticket/bug).

Interestingly, no in Chrome, it remembers all the session variable, the session ids are same and works fine. But in Firfox, it's not working!

Is there anyway to keep the session alive with the same id/ session variables alive so that even after the payment when they are returning, my application knows what the invoice number for this payment was.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Kind regards,
Tasin

Answer (score 0):

try turn off referer checks in core.php, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Domatic69, but can you elaborate this as I don't know which part I need to change. Do you mean this:Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false); as I has this as true before. This didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Security.level to something other than high in core.php.

Comment: I have already changed the security settings to low. No luck... :(

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't able to find a suitable solution for this problem, I had to find a work around for this.

As I mentioned, when redirecting, the 'Auth.User' information was still intact. I used this to retrieve information which I stored into the database before sending the users to the PayPal website.

Once the payment is completed and the user is returned to the confirmation page on my site, I am retrieving the data from the database based on 'Auth.User' session data.

Not the perfect solution, but for the time being, it is kind of working.

If welcome any solution that is better than this. Please let me know.

Many thanks,

Tasin